# Complex Mysql string not returning row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 rows on "Services" table:

```
ID | name | ObrID
 0 |   A  |  1
 1 |   B  |  2
 2 |   C  |  -1
```

-1 is a none existing Obr, the service 2 doesn't contains any Obr or it was deleted.

if i fetch with `select * from Services`, it works as expected, but if i do my search sql:

```
select 
    *,
    (select Name from Obrs where ID=ObrID) as ObrName
from
    Services
where
    (select Name from Obrs where ID=ObrID) like '%SEARCH_STRING%'
```

it doesn't return the last line. Is there any way so it return something like:

```
ID | name | ObrID | ObrName
 0 |   A  |   1   |   ObrA
 1 |   B  |   2   |   ObrB
 3 |   C  |   -1  |   NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use left join.

[http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php](http://left%20join%20tutorial)

```
SELECT s.*,o.ObrName from Services s
    LEFT JOIN Obrs o ON ID=ObrID
    WHERE OrbName LIKE '%$SEARCH_STRING%' OR OrbName IS NULL
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM (select s.*,o.ObrName from Services s
    LEFT JOIN Obrs o ON ID=ObrID) tmp
    WHERE OrbName LIKE '%$SEARCH_STRING%' OR OrbName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below can help:

```
select s.*,ob.Name from Services as s left join Obrs as ob on s.ID=ob.ObrID where  ob.Name like '%$SEARCH_STRING%';
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is no `Obrs.Name` because your `ObrID` is `-1`, then `Obrs.Name` will be `NULL` and therefor not `LIKE '%$SEARCH_STRING%'`. You can add an additional condition to also include these cases:

```
where 
    (select Name from Obrs where ID=ObrID) like '%$SEARCH_STRING%'
    OR ObrID = -1
```

And follow [Flöcsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10087745/1220835)'s suggestion and use a `LEFT JOIN`. Joins are always the preferred method, especially vs. correlated subquerys. The working condition when using a `LEFT JOIN` is

```
WHERE 
    Obrs.Name LIKE '%$SEARCH_STRING%'
    OR Obrs.Name IS NULL
```